# AlarmManager doesnt execute when close application

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I use this project for my application: https://github.com/nickfox/GpsTracker

When I run it in 4.4, everything is ok, the gps tracker still running when I close app. But in 5.0, it's not. The alarmmanager and service is close with application when close by Task manager.

What's problem with it??? Please help me fix it

seem like power managerment is close service when I close app. Can I add app to whitelist in api 21???

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check your `LocationService` class.

In its `onStartCommand` the `Service` returns `START_NOT_STICKY`, which means the OS will not restart this `Service` if it gets killed.

Try the following in `LocationService`:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // if we are currently trying to get a location and the alarm manager has called this again,
    // no need to start processing a new location.
    if (!currentlyProcessingLocation) {
        currentlyProcessingLocation = true;
        startTracking();
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: i found problem. That is Power management force it close. In api 23, maybe use REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS, but my asus fonepad 7 is api 21